# Move Screen to Right Without Monitor Buttons

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I have a monitor, which doesn't have buttons (quite unusual) and screen is moved to left for about 5cm. Any idea how to move screen from left to right?

Comment: Are you trying to say the image is offset/under the bezel? What model is your monitor? It can't not have an OSD ANYWHERE, especially if it supports VGA.

Comment: I mean that there is black line on the right side of the monitor and there is 5cm lost in the left side of the monitor. like windows start button is a little hidden

Comment: SAMSUNG SyncMaster SA100

Comment: Took me 2 seconds to find the answer on Google :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds. Then a menu should appear...

Press and hold it until it is over AUTO. Then tap the button once.

Comment: If you want to adjust any other settings, you need to download MagicTune from the Samsung website.

Answer (score 1):

1. right click mouse button.
2. double click Graphics properties.
3. Select Advance mode.
4. select monitor/tV setting.
5. and find position setting.
6. then custom your monitor display position.(some time it is under pop up menu).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Sony TV as a monitor and I was having the same problem. The graphic properties were not supported on my computer for this TV but I was able to fix the problem of the misaligned screen from my TV menu.

1. Use the TV remote to pull up the TV menu > Settings > PC Settings
2. Depending on which is your problem select Horizontal Center or Vertical Center and set to zero. When selecting either of those the screen moves as it would if you had the external buttons that a monitor usually has.

Comment: But OP has a normal monitor not TV